# How to extract data from the HTML using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How to extract the data from from the html ?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'http://book.ponniyinselvan.in/part-1/chapter-1.html'
page = urlopen(url)

getting HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I am trying to extract the data into CSV file.

Comment: Many web sites, to avoid rampant copyright violations, are only willing to work with genuine browsers.  You should look into the `User-Agent` header to get around that.  But this is a book of prose.  How are going to shove that into a CSV?  It doesn't seems like a smart approach.

Comment: Hi Tim,i found issues in while writing in csv , currently using txt instead of csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to save the text into a CSV file:

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://book.ponniyinselvan.in/part-1/chapter-1.html"

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    text = soup.section.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")

    writer.writerow(["Chapter", "Text"])
    writer.writerow([1, text])
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrej. is that possible to loop the extraction for all the pages automatically in that page?